# Architecture for Android app using GWT

Tags: android, gwt

I need to build Android application using Java which is able to send request to read or write some data to "database" or similar data store on google web server (using GWT technology). 
Android app should be able to authenticate user with Google Account, send request to server to add data to database on server, receive data form server. 
I would like to know what is the best approach and architecture I should use? What mechanism should I use to get data response over network (RPC, GET request)? What should I put on server side (servlet, ...) ? 
There is example how to build gwt app: which run 1. javascript in browser 2. servlet, service, serviceImpl, serviceAcynch, etc... I think this is no use for my app because I need to directly get and send data to/from server.

I need to have data exchange with GWT server to get/update coordinates for my Google MapView. Therefore I need to use data exchange mechanism between android client app and GWT.

---

Why do I need this on android? I have to be able to get GPS position of android device and update data with web server, then display my android device position on map. I need GWT to store, put, return position data (for example to show visited locations). Should it be build as Android native app? How can I update, get data from GWT server?

Comment: You have just described a mobile web application.  I don't see any point in developing this as native app.

Comment: A native app is something that gets installed on the phone, a web app is an application accessed through the web browser.  You description of the application does not contain any functionality that would require the construction of a native application, especially if your application is completely dependent on a web RPC interface.

Comment: Though as others have noted here you don't really describe a native app, if you want a native app for discoverability (app store), or some other reason you haven't mentioned, you might want to look at something like PhoneGap, and something such as GWT Mobile in conjunction with it. You don't have to use either to do what you describe, of course, but since you may already be familiar with GWT, those might be worth looking into.

Comment: Should I use Google App Engine instead of GWT? in order to: "I need to have data exchange with GWT server to get/update coordinates for my Google MapView. Therefore I need to use data exchange mechanism between android client app and GWT."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a general question. The best I can do is give you a general answer. For stuff like this, I like to build up a REST framework. REST is a robust and resilient paradigm which is something you need when developing mobile applications, the network connection could go out at any time. Using REST, you can just use standard HttpRequests to query the server. Responding to the requests server side is as simple as processing the HttpRequests. On Android, the HttpURLConnection class is perfect for this kind of stuff. If you want a rather complex but comprehensive example of all this, you can take a look at the SampleSyncAdapter example in the android SDK. Also, you might find this [Google IO video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) interesting. It's one of my favorites.

Comment: Thanks for the video. Unfortunately the link to `SampleSyncAdapter` is broken. I couldn't find the real link. It seems Google removed it (online). But the good news is you can always find it in SDK folder  :-)